# Invalid character ' ' in expression

Tags: awk, gawk, throughput

top of the day all .please I have checked the other errors that looked alike or wit hthe same error code. they seems not to be the same. I will need your help. hanks all

```
# Create awk program : myflowcalcall.awk

# a general script for computing throughput

BEGIN {
        arguments = 2;
     if (ARGC < arguments || ARGC > arguments || flowtype == 0) {
        printf("error: wrong number of arguments.\nawk: usage – awk -f flowcalc.awk [-v graphgran=value] [-v fidfrom=value] [-v fidto=value] [-v fid=value] -v flowtype=\"type\" -v outdata_file=\"filename\" indata_file\n–%d",ARGC);
        exit;
                                }
measure_interval = 0.5;
bits = 0;
first_time = graphgran;
    }

    {
    if (($1 == "r") &&
    ((fidfrom == 0 && fidto ==0) || (($8 == fid) && ($3 == fidfrom) && ($4 == fidto))) &&
    (flowtype == "all" || flowtype == $5)) {
if (($2 - first_time) > measure_interval)   {
    first_time = first_time + measure_interval;
    rate = (bits/1000000)/first_time;
    print filename first_time, rate;
                        }
bits = bits + $6 * 8;
                    }
    }
END {
measure_interval = 0.5;
first_time = first_time + measure_interval;
rate = (bits/1000000)/first_time;
print filename first_time, rate;
}
```

there is an error that

> awk: myflowcalcall.awk:20:     if (($2 – first_time) > measure_interval) {
>   awk: myflowcalcall.awk:20:             ^ invalid char '�' in expression

I have tried and checked  the error but to no avail. below is the command I gave to run from the terminal in Ubuntu 12.04LTS

> awk -f myflowcalcall.awk -v graphgran=0 -v fidfrom=2 -v fidto=3 -v fid=1 -v flowtype=”cbr” -v outdata_file=”nothing” johna4bp.tr > thr1

running the

```
xxd myflowcalcall.awk | grep " e2\|e2 "
```

produced

```
00000f0: 6177 6b3a 2075 7361 6765 20e2 8093 2061  awk: usage ... a
0000190: 6174 615f 6669 6c65 5c6e e280 9325 6422  ata_file\n...%d"
00002c0: 2828 2432 20e2 8093 2066 6972 7374 5f74  (($2 ... first_t
```

may I know the points of error. thanks all

Comment: The `”` looks bad. Change them for `"`.

Comment: Why they look so nice? :P

Comment: fedorqui thanks. I changed that and still gave an error of "awk: myflowcalcall.awk:20:     if (($2 – first_time) > measure_interval) {
awk: myflowcalcall.awk:20:             ^ invalid char '�' in expression
"

Comment: Mmmm can you update your question with the current code and also indicate which is the 20th line?

Comment: @fedorqui I have done that. thanks

Comment: The 20th line looks fine, so it looks like what @Joe indicates: some strange character is around there messing it.

Comment: I agree with the above comments. 1. I still don't see that you've marked line 20 in your code. 2. Does any output happen, if so this mean bad data. 3. try using `gawk --lint ....` . Maybe it will highlight the error better. Good luck!

Comment: @shellter thanks this is the 20th line of the code                                                                        if (($2 – first_time) > measure_interval) {

Comment: What does this show: `sed -n 20p myflowcalcall.awk | od -c`

Comment: the result is                                                        '0000000                  \t   i   f       (   (   $   2     342 200 223
        0000020       f   i   r   s   t   _   t   i   m   e   )       >       m
        0000040   e   a   s   u   r   e   _   i   n   t   e   r   v   a   l   )
 0000060      \t   {  \n
 0000064'

Answer (score 1):

you appear to have used a unicode-aware editor at some point that replaced some of your simple characters with similar multi-byte chars.

The codes for the quote and dash replacements start with e2, try

```
xxd myflowcalcall.awk | grep " e2\|e2 "
```

to find them

Comment: thanks. could you please give more explanation on that; do I need to use this line you gave to correct the code?

Comment: e2 is not a simple ascii character, so it shouldn't appear in an awk script.  This one-liner will simply show you where they appear in your code so you can remove them. 
I see 3 places in the above code:
the dash in usage - awk, -%d, and $2 - first_time

Comment: in your xxd output, look for e2 80 93 in the hexadecimal part, which is shown as ... in the text part.  This indicates a UTF-8 en-dash, when what you need is a hypen-minus (hex code 2d)

Answer (score 1):

Look at your code, I do see an issue with `-` character. Some are longer than the other which means they are not interpreted correctly.

Comment: thanks for the time. I have change them but it is still the same error that I got.

Comment: @forgoodGOD Can you please update your question with modified code?

Comment: thanks all. I modified the file again and give no error again but it produces a result of 0.5 instead of a series of data in a column.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newbie to scripting but isn't first_time= graphgran supposed to be first_time=graphgran 
 I mean without a whitespace?